# App Crashing when adding Share button to Action Bar

Tags: android, share

App Crashes when I try to add Share button to Action Bar. Below is my res/main.xml and also my onCreateOptionsMenu, including my logCat. Failing line number is 1077, I have highlighted that below.

**FAILING LINE -->    myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);**

In my res/main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.devmav.focusoutfacebook.MainActivityCircularSeekbar"

>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

</menu>
```

In My main Activity extending class, following is my **onCreateOptionsMenu** implementation.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        ShareActionProvider myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Whatever message you want to share");
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");


                //THIS IS LINE 1077 THAT IS FAILING
        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);



        return true;


    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**LogCat Error Output**:

```
 06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): java.lang.NullPointerException
    **06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):   at     com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook.MainActivityCircularSeekbar.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivityCircularSeekbar.java:1077)**
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at    android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    06-10 03:48:20.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: may be you are getting null pointer because of shareactionprovider isn't assigned properly

Comment: try uncommenting the `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside of a null check first like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.feed, menu);
    // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionProvider(shareItem);

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mStory.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mStory.getDescription() + "\n"
                + mStory.getUrl() + "\n\n\n" + "Blah blah blah");

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Also make sure that the `extras` you are putting in your `Intent` are not `null`! In the past I had created a `shareActionProvider` and received a `NullPointerException` because the `Intent-Extras` were `null`!

Comment: I am getting a null condition, you are right about that. But curious - where are you getting this implementation of onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)? I get only one parameter, Menu, as i pasted, but you have two parameters. When I try your code snipped, I see no collapsed three dots on the Action Bar.

Comment: This is the `onCreateOptionsMenu` for a fragment, same idea just a little different implementation.